# PHP Fatal error en consulta Selects dependientes

Tags: php

Estoy atascada con un tema de una práctica de clase que es aparentemente sencillo pero me está dando problemas, un simple select combinado. Hago un select a una tabla postgres y se rellena el select con los valores de la tabla,  envío los parámetros para rellenar el siguiente select y me salta el siguiente error para la siguiente consulta:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in /var/www/html/page1.php 
Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/page1.php on line ...
```

Código HTML

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    include 'conexion.php';
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $cnn = $conexion->getConexion();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Sel_uno").on('change', function () {
        $("#Sel_uno option:selected").each(function () {
            var id_do = $(this).val();
            $.post("page2.php", { id_do: id_do }, function(data) {
                $("#Sel_dos").html(data);
            });         
        });
   });
});
</script>
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <!-- select principal -->
        <select id="Sel_uno" name="Sel_uno">
            <option value=" ">Select O.D...</option>
            <?php
            $statement = $cnn->prepare('SELECT c_data.do_s.id_do, c_data.do_s.do_name FROM c_data.do_s ORDER BY c_data.do_s.do_name');
            $statement->execute();

            while( $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo "<option value=" . $row['id_do'] . ">" .$row['do_name'] . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <!-- segundo select -->
        <div class="caja">
            <select id="Sel_dos" name="Sel_dos"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Veo que el valor del **id_do** lo pasa a la siguiente página:

```
id_do: 2 // por ejemplo
```

código de page2.php

```
<?php
    include 'Conexion.php';
    
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $cnn = $conexion->getConexion();
    
    $id_do = $_POST['id_do'];
    
    $result = $cnn->query('select c_data.tabla.id_do, c_data.tabla.code, c_data.tabla.do_name
        from c_data.tabla order by c_data.tabla.do_name where c_data.tabla.id_do = ".$id_do."');
    
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value=" . $row['id_do'] . ">" .$row['do_name'] . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

Cambié el primer select haciendo una query normal sin prepararla pero así no me carga los datos de la tabla entonces volví a hacer una consulta preparada.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, el problema lo tenía en el segundo php

```
<?php
    include 'conexion.php';
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $cnn = $conexion->getConexion();

    $id_do = $_POST['id_do'];


    $query="select c_data.tabla.id_do, c_data.tabla.code, c_data.tabla.do_name
        from c_data.tabla order by c_data.tabla.do_name where c_data.tabla.id_do = "$id_do" order by c_data.tabla.do_name';
        
    $statement = $cnn->prepare( $query );
    
    $statement->execute();
    
    $html = "<option value=''>Select...</option>";
    
    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {                
            $html.= "<option value=" .$row['id_do'] . ">" .$row['cadastralc'] . "</option>";
        }
    echo $html;
?>
```